# NetBeans profiler cannot find project dependency while compiler can

Tags: netbeans, profiling

(Netbeans version: 7.01 on Fedora 15)

I have a NetBeans Java SE project "A" which uses classes from a NetBeans Java SE library project "B".

I added project B as a library under Libraries->Compile in the project properties of A. The dependency works fine when running or debugging the application, but if I try to run the profiler I get "cannot find symbol" errors for the classes from project B.

What is the actual problem and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Temporary solution: Clean and build your project A before profiling. It solves the problem for me.